# mysqld_safe unknown option '--character-set-server=utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Following [this tutorial](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/03/31/using-emojis-in-django-model-fields).

/etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Error log when starting:

```
Oct 26 18:21:27 server systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Oct 26 18:21:28 server mysqld_safe[12898]: 181026 18:21:28 mysqld_safe unknown option '--character-set-client-handshake=FALSE'
Oct 26 18:21:28 server mysqld_safe[12898]: 181026 18:21:28 mysqld_safe unknown option '--character-set-server=utf8mb4'
Oct 26 18:21:28 server mysqld_safe[12898]: 181026 18:21:28 mysqld_safe unknown option '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
Oct 26 18:21:28 server mysqld_safe[12898]: 181026 18:21:28 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Oct 26 18:21:28 server mysqld_safe[12898]: 181026 18:21:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Oct 26 18:21:30 server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 26 18:21:30 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
```

Any idea why these options are not recognized?

The tutorial said it was not required, just recommended. Indeed it worked without these configuration modifications, but maybe I should have them.

Comment: You're using a 4-year old tutorial for MySQL, but your database is not MySQL, it's MariaDB. Probably has something to do with it!

Comment: Set them in the config file, and forget about doing it on `mysqld_safe`.